# Expected expression before { token

Tags: c, циклы, синтаксис

Написал программу, которая подсчитывает количество единиц в двоичном представлении числа. Не могу найти внятного объяснения, как убрать этот баг - expected expression before. В программе три таких ошибки.

```c
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
  int a, i, mass[99];
  for (i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    mass[i] = 0;
  }
  scanf  ("%d", &a);
  i = 0;
  while (a != 0) {
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
      mass[i] = 0;
      a = a / 2;
    } else {
      mass[i] = 1;
      a = a / 2;
    }
  i++;
  }
  i = i - 1;
  for (; i >= 0; i--){
      printf("%d", mass[i]);
  }
  int sum = 0;
  size_t w = sizeof(mass) / sizeof(int);
  for (int r = 0, r < w, r++) {
    if (mass[i] == 1) {
      sum += 1;
    }
  }
  printf("%d", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В заголовке цикла `for` части отделяются точками с запятыми, а не запятыми...